# Unable to unzip file created in PHP after downloading it through a browser

Tags: php, download, zip, unzip

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $filename = $first_name . ".zip";

    if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
    }

    $zip->addFile($first_name . ".clean");
    $zip->addFile($first_name . ".log");
    $zip->addFile($first_name . ".result");
    $zip->addFile($first_name . ".txt");
    $zip->close();

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($filename));
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); // no cache
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    ob_end_flush();
    readfile("$filename");
```

I tried to create a .zip file through PHP code and download it on localhost through a browser. The downloaded zip is unable to unzip and gives an error message like this:

Archive:  upload_pnt-prs.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of upload_pnt-prs.zip or
        upload_pnt-prs.zip.zip, and cannot find upload_pnt-prs.zip.ZIP, period.

I have tried out some solutions that are already answered but that is not fixing my problem. Please help for it....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should re-arrange the header sequence.
I tried the code below and it work

```
header('Pragma: public');   // required
header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($filename)).' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename)); // provide file size
header('Connection: close');
readfile($filename);
exit();
```

Hopefully this will be useful for you